# Tons of problems a new user is encountering

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I've borrowed this laptop from a friend. I wanted to install AdBlock to boost performance. First weird thing was that even though I was on Chrome, Chrome suggested me installing him?

So I tried to install ,than it gave me some message about broken dependencies. I Googled and tried to run those commands you guys were suggesting, but than it popped up error messages about everything again.

Than I found out that some package called linux image generic is broken, than I tried to find an answer to that, but on the topic it was ” ndk.bhj\spo;ujvsdljvaEOYUFgidgAPIF;hsgvk in other words, I didn't understand anything about it, than there's this thing: `E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?`

Seriously, when I'm trying to fix an error, there is another one.
I'm on something called GNOME.
 Sooo, where do I start?

Comment: You'd start by telling us what you've actually been running. Adblock is a browser extension so I've no idea why you'd be touching anything that required package dependencies, let alone getting yourself into the state where you've broken system dependencies.

Comment: Basically, the problem occurred when I was trying to install Chrome (which was already running in front of my own eyes!)
I tried: sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude install gtkorphan
and: sudo sh -c "apt-get update;apt-get dist-upgrade;apt-get autoremove;apt-get autoclean"

Answer (score 0):

[Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/how-do-i-fix-a-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-problem/15469#15469) will solve the lock problem.

on the command line, type `sudo apt-get -f install` to see if you can fix the dependencies issue after the lock problem is fixed.

The other option is to use Synaptic under System in the menu.  You can click on the edit menu to find the fix dependencies option.

Comment: "rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/apt/lists/lock': No such file or directory"

while trying to resolve the lock